# can't load images when using webpack-dev-server with HMR config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I created a React project with webpack2, and previewed the result by using webpack-dev-server. At first, I just used the CLI to enable HMR as follows:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

everything is ok.

Then, I wanted to enable HMR by setting up webpack.config.js, but failed.
The browser doesn't show me the images and the console is always show the 404 error as below:

[image for error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NSu.png)

I looked for the methods all day and changed the config file many times, but made no difference. Any help would be great appreciate.

My project structure:

```
|--dist
|  |--index.html
|--src
|  |--images
|  |  |--logo.png
|  |--js
|     |--components
|     |  |--pc_header.js
|     |--index.js
|--package.json
|--webpack.config.js
```

**package.json**

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),

entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',  
    './index.js'
],

output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
},

devtool: 'inline-source-map',

devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']        
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: 'style-loader',
              use: 'css-loader'
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
            use: ['file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]']
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[name].css'
    })
]
```

};

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
</div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

**pc_header.js**

```
render(){
  return (
     <img src='../../images/logo.png' alt="logo"/>
}
```

Maybe there's something wrong with my path config, but I have tried all kinds of path config, and use import LogoImg from "../../images/logo.png" in the file pc_header.js，all failed. Now I have no idea about this headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your webpack config, your file loader for images is: `['file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]']`, which will output images to `/img/name.ext`

but you are using `/image/` instead.

however, it's better to do

`import logo from '../../logo.png';`

in your components

then

just use it as a variable `<img src={logo} alt="logo"/>`

so webpack will handle the path for you.
The reason of letting webpack to handle path is you can take the advantage of keeping images by components, eg:

```
|--MyComponent
|    |-- component.js
|    |-- images
|        |---a.png
|        |---b.png
```

but when you build for production you can put all in one single folder eg `assets/images`

If you feel there are too much imports, you can create a kind of index.js in images folder

eg.

```
export { default as a } from './a.png;
export { default as b } from './b.png;
export { default as c } from './c.png;
```

then

```
import {a, b, c } from './images';
```

Comment: First, I changed `use: ['file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]']` to `use: ['file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]']` , and also use `<img src='../../images/logo.png' alt="logo"/>`, the console also show the error`logo.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/images/logo.png 404 (Not Found)`. Second, in the config file , I also use `use: ['file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]']`, and in my conponents, use `import  logo from '../../images/logo.png'`, the error becomes `images/logo.png:1 GET http://images/logo.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. May be I don't catch your idea...

Comment: please remove the leading slash to `['file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]']`, also can you try to console.log(logo); in your render method ? and make sure you use  `src={logo}`

Comment: Thanks very muck. The leading slash tricked me, After removing it, the two ways before are effective. Out of curiousity, if my app needs more `<img>`, Should I have to use more and more `import pic from "... ..."`? To many `import`?

Comment: at the end, you are typing the same amount of times the image url, I updated the answer

Comment: Your detailed answer solved my problem perfectly. Thanks for your patience and kindness!